# Exact meaning of asymptotic notation.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

In our number theory course,we have been introduced to big-$O$-notation,small-$o$-notation and asymptotic notation.I want to understand what the asymptotic notation $f\sim g$ mean for $f,g:\mathbb {R\to R}$.Does  $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$ mean that  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ behave almost same when $x$ is sufficiently large i.e. the values of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are very close.But in that case,why we do not have $|f(x)-g(x)|\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$,because that also means that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are close.I want explanation whether there is a difference between $f(x)-g(x)\to 0$ and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to 1$,if yes please provide some example.

Comment: Take for example $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^2+x$, or $g(x)=x^2+\sin x$. Note that $|f-g|$ is an absolute difference and $\big|\frac{f}{g}-1\big|$ is a *relative* difference.

Comment: Consider $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x+1$, or $f(x)=x+\sqrt x$....

Comment: $f(x) - g(x) \rightarrow 0$ is stronger.  eg consider that \$1,012,000 is close to \$1,000,000 in the sense that it's only 1.2% more, however, in absolute terms the difference of \$12,000 is still pretty large.

Comment: @GregMartin I am able to show that $f\sim g \nRightarrow f-g\to 0$ by taking $f(x)=x+\log x$ and $g(x)=x$

Comment: @JairTaylor Not always so, take for example $f(x)=1/x, g(x)=1/x^2$ then $f-g \to 0$ but $\frac{f}{g} \to \infty$.

Comment: @JairTaylor So does $f-g\to 0$ imply $f\sim g$?

Comment: It certainly does, and you’ll benefit from proving this.

Comment: @AlonAmit No,because take $f(x)=1/x$ and $g(x)=1/x^2$.

Comment: That’s right. I was implicitly assuming that f and g tend to infinity, which I thought was the context of your question.